# Get all days from given month&year with Azure synapse dataflow expression

Tags: expression, dataflow, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I need help with getting the dates of a given month&year. I am using Azure Synapse Dataflow Expression and tried different things but I could not do it. There is no other similar question for Dataflow here.

I also tried following but get Null value out.

**toDate(concat(concat({PeriodeMåned},'-'),{PeriodeRegnskapsår}),'yyyyMMdd')**

I have the following format:
[f.eks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr66Q.png)

Looking for a list of all the dates in the following format.

[How I need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2rgv.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give us the full data of the source? What's the the column 'PeriodeManed' and 'PeriodeRegnskapsar' ? what's meaning of 'get all days from givem month and year' ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that. PeriodeRegnskapar is "Year" column and  PeriodeManed is Month Column. 

And as i you can see in the images given in the main question, if i have 

|ID|PeriodeManed|PeriodeRegnskapar|
|--|------------|-------------- --|
|A1|feb         | 2019            |
|A2|aug         | 2019            |

output:

| ID | PeriodeManed | PeriodeRegnskapar | Alldays |  |
|-|-|-|-|-|
| A1 | feb | 2019 | 01.02.2029 |  |
| A1 | feb | 2019 | 02.02.2019 |  |
| A2 | march | 2019 | 01.03.2019 |  |